# Can I take a skill feat that that is linked to an archetype without having this archetype?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, feat-qualifications

Consider a skill feat like [Tattoo Artist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2962). Is it possible to take that at level 3 if I don't have [Runelord Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3020)?

My guts say no, but I haven't found the rule.

As an argument for yes, non-skill feats that are parts of archetypes clearly indicate that requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Generally no, you need the Dedication

Most archetype skill feats, such as [Graceful Leaper](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1876), have the Dedication Feat as a Prerequisite.

> **Prerequisites** Acrobat Dedication; master in Acrobatics

### Tattoo Artist is different

Tattoo Artist is a *skill feat* first and foremost. In Secrets of Magic, it is found first in the Magical Tattoos section (p164) and only has trained (Crafting) as a Prereq. It is included as an [Additional Feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1432) for Runelords on p240. The primary benefit of this seems to be that it counts any time you need to know how many "Runelord Feats" you have.

Comment: So, the specific answer here is that you don't need to have the Runelord Dedication to take Tattoo Artist. But if you had the Runelord Dedication, it would count towards the number of feats you need to take before taking another dedication.